# Checking the regional settings

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

In my app I need to check if the regional settings are russian on the computer it's running on. Also, I need to know if russian keyboard layout is installed.

The intention behind this is to know whether this computer **is likely** (I don't need to be 100% sure, likely is good enough) to be owned by a russian. The idea is to check if the regional settings are set to russian, and/or if there is a russian keyboard layout installed, as those are both likely to be present in a computer owned by a russian, but unlikely to be present on a computer owned, say, by an american.

Btw it's not really about russian, it's other nationalities I'll check for, I was just using it as an example.

How can I check those?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322578/win32-api-for-getting-the-languagelocalization-info-of-the-os

Comment: Could you give us a better indication for the reasoning behind it? For instance, does a GeoIP-based solution make sense for you? Looking at my russian colleagues, I can't see any of them with a russian keyboard.

Comment: @msalters What is GeoIP exactly? I tried a cursory search in google but it didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

[National Language Support Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319081%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a good place to start.

You need to decide which info you want - You can check which locales are existing, installed, system default, user default or active for a thread. `GetThreadLocale` will tell you the active locale for a thread, `GetUserDefaultLCID` and `GetSystemDefaultLCID` will tell you defaults, the `EnumSystemLocales` function will let you see which locales exist/are installed, or you can use `IsValidLocale` to check if a specific locale is installed.